# php reverse imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php, binary

Is there a way to turn a jpg to string, reverse of `imagecreatefromstring`?
I have to communicate to a server which needs binary of image, i saw plenty of jpg to binary but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagecreatefromstring` takes a string which contains the binary data of an image and turns it into a gd image resource so you can manipulate it with the gd image library. Literally the "reverse" of that would be `imagejpeg`, which saves a gd image resource to a jpeg image.

I guess what you really want though is simply the initial string, which contains the binary data of the image to begin with. I.e.:

1. `$imageString = file_get_contents('image.jpg');`
2. `$gd = imagecreatefromstring($imageString);`

Just skip step 2.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark here... No real experience with this, just my thoughts after looking through some documentation...

I see in the documentation of [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) an example is given where a base64 encoded string is converted into an image. Taking that example and flipping it around might just be what you are looking for.

```
$image = file_get_contents('image_file.jpg');
$imageString = base64_encode($image);
```